# tomcat or root password in Azure Bitnami

Tags: azure, tomcat, passwords, root, azure-virtual-machine

All,

I brought a Tomcat 8 server by Bitnami from Azure and setup a default app username and password for the server.

After logging in, I am trying to deploy a war file in the webapps folder but I see that other than the "tomcat" user, no one else has write permissions. Please note that I have logged in as my own appuser though it says "bitnami@". I am just trying to understand as to how can I get the

1. root password; or
2. Tomcat user password; and
3. Why does it say bitnami even though I have logged in as a different user?

[image: screenshot showing the webapps folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Root password of Tomcat 8 server by Bitnami

Root password **same** as your login password. Also we can use `sudo -i` change to root.

```
bitnami@vm1:~$ sudo -i
root@vm1:~#
```

> tomcat user password

We can login as root then **switch** to tomcat

```
bitnami@vm1:~$ sudo -i
root@vm1:~# su - tomcat
tomcat@vm1:~$
```

Also we can find the configure file of tomcat users.tomcat's password is **must be changed**.

```
root@vm1:/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/conf# pwd
/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/conf
root@vm1:/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/conf# cat tomcat-users.xml
<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="<must-be-changed>" roles="role1"/>
-->
<user username="manager" password="NqIQgA6eQrPp" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

so we can use command to **change** tomcat password:

```
root@vm1:~# passwd tomcat
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
root@vm1:~# exit
logout
bitnami@vm1:~$ su - tomcat
Password: 
tomcat@vm1:~$
```

> why does it say bitnami eventhough I have logged in as a different
>   user

We can check `/etc/passwd` to find the configure of users:

```
root@vm1:/# cat /etc/passwd
sshd:x:104:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
pollinate:x:105:1::/var/cache/pollinate:/bin/false
bitnami:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu:/home/bitnami:/usr/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:106:112:ftp daemon,,,:/srv/ftp:/bin/false
bitnamiftp:x:1000:1000::/opt/bitnami/apps:/bin/bitnami_ftp_false
mysql:x:1001:1002::/home/mysql:
tomcat:x:999:999::/home/tomcat:
jason:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu:/home/jason:/bin/bash
```

In this way, we can find **all** users in this VM, your **username** and **bitnami** have the **same uid and gid**, we can use `id` to check it:

```
bitnami@vm1:~$ id jason
uid=1000(bitnami) gid=1000(bitnami) groups=1000(bitnami),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),102(netdev),1001(bitnami-admins)
```